# Security of Unlinking uploaded tmp file (PHP)

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, unlink

I found this code in a gallery script. (I have simplified it a bit.)

```
if (
        !eregi("\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$", $input_files['name'][$i])
        ||
        (!is_uploaded_file($input_files['tmp_name'][$i]))
        ||
        intval($input_files['error'][$i])
        ||
        !intval($input_files['size'][$i])
        ||
        !in_array($input_files['type'][$i], array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/x-png'))
        )
{
    @unlink($input_files['tmp_name'][$i]);
}
```

The $input_files is an array of files posted to the script.

The script checks the extensions, upload errors, file size, etc. in a loop.

But isn't it insecure to unlink the tmp file in this case?
If the file is NOT an uploaded file, the tmp_name value could contain any possible path.

Comment: Fyi, `eregi()` is deprecated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the tmp_name value could contain any possible path."?

Comment: Technically the file will get deleted when the script has finished running anyway, as it's only a temporary file

Comment: unlink will not delete a directory that has any contents inside of it and based on what user/group PHP is running under your OS, it will have to have sufficient privileges to unlink the targeted file. So unless you have PHP running under root user/group, I wouldn't be too worried. ( +1 on eregi deprecation )

Comment: Is the temp filename chosen by the server or the user?